# Fundamental group of disjoint union of circles

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have the following question:
What is the fundamental group of disjoint union of n circles?
My intuition tells me is Fn however I am not sure how to prove it. Does anyone know any proof for that
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to pick a basepoint. The fundamental group depends only on the path-component your basepoint is, so no matter what basepoint you choose, it will be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Do you mean the wedge sum of $n$ circles instead?

Comment: no disjoint circles. Maybe my intuition is wrong  and it's not Fn

Comment: The use of the words "**the** fundamental group" applied to a _space_ is a conceptual mistake;  the term  applies only to a _space with base point_, which is a different concept. It might be thought there is not much difference, but that is wrong. It may even prevent people thinking of having more than one base point! **The** fundamental group of the coproduct (as spaces with base point) of $n$ circles is indeed the free group on $n$ elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental group will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Pick some base point $p$ in one of the circles. The problem here is that the fundamental group cannot detect the other circles because any loop $\gamma$ about $p$ must stay within the path component containing $p$. This component is a single one of the circles. Thus, the fundamental group will be isomorphic to the fundamental group of the circle, which is just $\mathbb{Z}$ up to isomorphism.